# Facebook app hosted on SSL gives "Connection not trusted" error for some visitors

Tags: facebook, ssl

I have developed a Facebook app that works well for me using IE11, FireFox latest and Chrome latest.

I am hosting it on my domain with an SSL certificate, and the app is set up correctly in Facebook Developer portal.

The client, however, see "Connection not trusted" error message using FireFox latest.

I also occasionally get this problem when browsing https to some of my other domains using my phone, so I do not think this is in particularly a Facebook problem, but more something with my hosting or SSL certificates as my host installed them.

My question is: What can cause "Certificate not trusted" errors intermittently? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that one of the site URLs needed a '/' at the end. The problem is gone after adding that '/'.